# find the maximum

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I'm stuck in this problem (Instructions and my work is showed on the picture below) I just don't know what to do right after find the values of D, to prove that the maximum of F(D) is attained at the smaller of the two positive solution of the equation. Please see my work in the picture below[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

First of all, we need to make sure that $\alpha$ is negative such that the function $f(D) = \alpha D^2 + \beta D + M_o^2$ opens downward.

If yes, then a maximum is attained at $D = - \frac {\beta }{2\alpha}$ and the maximum value is given by $f(\frac {-\beta}{2\alpha})$.

Comment: I have a question. What about F(-B/2alpha)? it is undefined. since the denominator is zero

Comment: If $\alpha$ is $0$, then the equation is quadratic no more. It is reduced to $\beta D + M_o^2 = 0$. From which, D is simply.....

Comment: I mean when you plug -B/2alpha on F(D) then we have m0/v(1-(am0/c0(m0-m0)) do you see my point? we have am0/0 that is undefined

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have my answer edited such that my f is different from your F.